# Can't find objects in my database within month filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to display a count of the mentioned objects using this piece of code:

```
day = datetime.date.today()
MyModel.objects.filter(submit_date__month=day.month).count()
```

This returns 0. Trying from a different approach:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(submit_date__month=day.month).all()
```

Still, it returns a empty queryset.

Below, a picture with the dates of the entries in the database, which are stored in a DateTimeField with default=timezone.now.

[image: Said objects]

P.S.: USE_TZ = True, TIME_ZONE = 'America/Bahia'

---

UPDATE: Figured out a workaround

```
queryset_count = 0

for a in MyModel.objects.filter(submit_date__year=day.year):
        if a.submit_date.month == day.month:
            queryset_count += 1
```

I still don't know why the queryset behaved like this, but as time was catching me up, this solved the issue in its own way.

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns a empty queryset"? `.count()` will return an integer not a queryset

Comment: check if the queryset is empty without the count function by printing it somewhere. Like @IainShelvington said count() returns a number

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I tested it in several ways, the count was just one of them.  Fixed the question.